# Safari: adding click / touchstart event listeners not working

Tags: javascript, ios

I am trying this in Safari in the console. I'm trying to just print out the target of the click / tap but nothing is getting printed when I tap on any where on the screen. This is what I have entered:

```
document.querySelector("body").addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) { console.log(e.target); });
document.querySelector("body").addEventListener('click', function(e) { console.log(e.target); });
```